# how to disable copying a picture from excel

Tags: c#, excel

I have sucessfully inserted image to excel sheet.Now i should not allow the picture to be copied by anyone. how can i achieve this?
any idea.

thanks in advance.

Comment: Don't tell me what I can and can't do with files on my computer.  Do tell me which company you work for so I can avoid their products.

Comment: If a picture can be seen, it can be copied.

Comment: Karl: you don't happen to own any tech products do you? All products limit what you can and can't do with them.

Answer (score 4):

You can't.

Of course, there are certain measures you could employ, but there are always ways around them. You could (somehow) disable copy & paste within Excel, but then the user could take a screenshot (Alt-PrtScn) and crop it in an image editor.

If you somehow disable the ability to take a screenshot, they may feed the monitor output of their machine to another machine with a screen grabber, and get the image that way.

Or, of course, accepting the loss of quality, they could point a camera at their screen and get it that way.

Comment: Forgot to say (as per Karls comment in reply to the question), if you do go down this route, don't expect to be popular with your users

Answer (score 4):

If your excel file is accessible by anyone, then you can't.

You can only shrink the images to low resolution or putting watermark on it.

Answer (score 2):

Depending on your environment and audience (eg, an internal document in your company), [Office IRM](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/help/HA101029181033.aspx) can prevent the document from being copied and even copied using print-screen.
Personally, I see these attempts as naive at best - the data can be easily copied anyway (for example by taking a photo of the screen), but it sends the right message to your colleagues.